# Why should one validate data if it is already sanitized?

Tags: php, api, security, backend

I was researching best practices of security for a php rest api backend. I read in many places you should sanitize and validate all user input. In my understanding, sanitizing would be removing dangerous characters from strings and validating would guarantee that a value is what the server expected to be like field name is a string. I understood the value of sanitizing to security as a way to avoid xss attacks, but I didn't understand the benefit to security of validating.

Comment: What if you get data you don't want to handle? For instance, would you save malformed email addresses (as an example).

Comment: As @JayBlanchard said, you may get input from the client that will 'look' ok to the system, but not be.

For example if you remove illegal chars from a form, and the visitor was trying to hit your SQL db with commands, then you wouldn't really want even the sanitised input going through as legit message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data sanitization is a mandatory process which affects the security of your system, by preventing malicious code injection.

On the other hand, data validation is a business logic process, which affects the integrity of your data. It is not mandatory in every system, however, not validating the data received in the backend may lead to unstability. For example, in an ecommerce you may have a special voucher that can be applied only to people above 65. Your validation process should check the date of birth of the user before letting him apply the voucher. This logic should be duplicated both in backend and frontend.

The frontend is your first line of defence, it shouldn't let the user perform any illegal operation. However, the frontend is just a nice interface sending requests to your API. Any check and validation performed in the frontend can be circumvented if the API requests are reverse engineered and manipulated.

So, even if your frontend doesn't let the user activate a voucher if under the required age, a specially crafted request to your API may be able to use the voucher if there is no validation in the backend. This is the purpose of data validation. Even when the data is sanitized and the API request "looks OK"  in that it doesn't have malformed data types or strange characters in the input, the request shouldn't be accepted due to a business requirement, and not for a security reason.

But, what's the deal on validating through frontend as well? Well, we have the better user experience by showing a nice error message instead of a usually less fancy API error, and we also avoid unnecessary API requests and validations if the request is anticipated to fail.

In conclusion, data validation is a recommended process that will lead to a better user experience and prevent data integrity issues, which are no less important than the system security.